# Delete word before and after Space

Tags: notepad++, regex

I hope anyone has an solution for my problem.

I have a format likes this:

```
0500380 Thomas
0800251 Peter
0682006 Martin
```

I want two solutions:

**First:**

```
0500380 
0800251 
0682006
```

*Delete everything after space*

**Second:**

```
Thomas
Peter
Martin
```

*Delete everything before space*

Comment: Is it a literal tab character?

Comment: Its a space....

Comment: Please [edit] the question to make that clear.

Comment: Okay, done now...

Comment: I think First should be "Delete everything after space" and Second "Delete everything before space" according to your examples. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Do you want the space removed as well?

Answer (score 6):

#### Delete everything after space

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(\w+) (\w+)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression"

[image]

---

#### Delete everything before space

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(\w+) (\w+)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"

[image]

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: @Grevensteiner Great! If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Actually, you can write `^.*? (\w+)$` and `^(\w+).*$`, using the replacement `$1` (prefer the ``$`` over the ``\`` due to escape sequences).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel *Shrug*. There are usually many different regular expressions to solve these kinds of problems. For a one-off I just use the first one which works and in this case I only had to change 1 character to get both cases working :)

Comment: For a one-off, for a small file, yours is perfectly fine. For a one-off with a large file, mine's a little better